# I need help to implement Cut command for Nattable

Tags: nattable

I have try DeleteSelectionHandler with copy command.It works but paste is not working.Copy and paste is working fine.But when i have used Cut( Copy,Delete).Cut works fine but not able to paste data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work with the existing functionalities in NatTable. Copy + Paste is working internally with cell references. That means when you delete the content in one cell, the stored reference is containing no data anymore that can be copied. For Cut + Paste you need to implement some mechanism that takes the data from the clipboard and prepares is back for pasting again. Similar task to perform when trying to do a copy paste action between different NatTable instances.

For those use cases you always need to work with the clipboard and handle the data there. And that handling is always dependent on your table structure. For example if you have different data types per column, cut + paste could cause data conversion exceptions.